# RowDefinition Height = Auto doesn't work?

Tags: c#, wpf, rowdefinition

Please have a look at my code below:

```
<Border Background="#242328" CornerRadius="10" Opacity="0.9">
    <Grid Width="400">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding [someViewModel].Title}" Margin="0,20,0,20"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding [someViewModel].AnotherText}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Source="{Binding [someViewModel].source}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding [someViewModel].AnotherText2}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid Grid.Row="3" Width="250" Margin="0,10,10,10">
            <Button Width="120" Height="50" Background="#638699" Content="OK" FontSize="18"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Output of the code above:

[image]

Now my question very simple, why there is empty space above the button? I've already set all `RowDefinition Height="Auto"`, when there isn't any value in my variable, shouldn't the box shrink to left only button?

Please note that all the variable such as *[someViewModel].Title, [someViewModel].AnotherText, [someViewModel].AnotherText2, [someViewModel].Source* will be null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at your designer and you will see something like this

[image: Designer]

Your TextBlock and StackPanels will be rendered and it doesn't matter if they have a value or not. If you want to hide them when they don't have a value you can use an IValueConverter to determine their visibilty based on their content.

Comment: If that's the case, what's the point of using `RowDefinition Height="Auto"?`

Comment: It will size the row height according to the size of it's contents. If the size of the contents change at runtime, so will the size of the Row. And your controls are still there. Doesn't matter if they have a value or not. Like I said: you will have to set the Visbility to collapsed if you don't want to show them. A good way would be to use a converter.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your controls in the `Auto` sized rows do have a height > 0 even if they don't display anything. This causes the calculated row height to also be > 0.

For example the `Margin` on your `TextBlock` causes a calculated height.
Also the `Image` control height is set to 100, no matter if you assign a source or not.